# How do I programmatically load a custom block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I created a new custom block type in /admin/structure/block/block-content/types to which I added two fields. Then, I created a block with that block type.

How can I programmatically load this block via code?

How do I get the values of its fields (*x*, an image field, and *y*, a text field)?

I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```php
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
$render = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
```

Answer (score 8):

Place the block in the disabled section at admin/structure/block, this creates a block instance with your block_content type, give it a nice easy machine name to remember.

[image: place block in disabled section]

By placing it in the disabled section, it won't show up, until you load it programatically.

Then using your machine name:

```
$machine_name = 'myblock';

$block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('block')
  ->load($machine_name);
if (!empty($block)) {
  $block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);

  $pre_render = $block_content;
}
```

If you really want to get the rendered fields, you can do:

```
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->build($pre_render);
```

But it is more standard practice to use Drupal's formatters and such and perhaps a custom template, rather than building the block and extracting elements from the rendered render array.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions. How to load and render a configured block  is answered perfectly by @oknate.

For the second question, *How do I get the values of its fields (*x*, an image field, and *y*, a text field)?* That's easy, because you've already loaded the block content entity, where the fields are stored in the database.

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
```

You can access the value from the text field

```
$text = $block->field_y->value;
```

and get the url from the image field.

```
$image_url = file_create_url($block->field_x->entity->uri->value);
```

Comment: $bid is the block content id. You see this in the url: /block/[bid]. This is the same as $nid is for a node: /node/[nid]

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216672/how-to-get-a-field-value-of-custom-block

Answer (score 0):

Try this code by including `EntityInterface`:

```
// Block 
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
// the last part of the parameter is the block id
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('yourblockid');
$block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($block_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$block = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('block_content', $uuid);
      if (!empty($block)) {
        $recArticleAdView = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
          ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
          ->view($block);
        $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($recArticleAdView);
        $response = new CacheableResponse($rendered);
        $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($recArticleAdView));
        $variables['content']['sponsored_content'] = Markup::create(trim(strip_tags($response->getContent(), '<div>')));
      }
```