# Get the time a custom block was last edited

Tags: blocks

I have seen lots of answers for getting when a node was last edited, but I can't seem to apply any of these methods to blocks. Basically, I have a block that I only want to display if it has been updated in the last week. When I view blocks in the admin, I see that the admin view shows you when a block was last edited.

I can get my block in hook_preprocess_block, and get things like $block->label(), but any variation of `$block->getChangedTime();` or `$block->changed;` fails for me.

And really, I need this value in my html template, not the block. So I need to get the specific block by ID, in hook_preprocess_html, get the time it was last updated as a unix timestamp, and this would give me the value I need for my twig template.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method of content entities implementing the EntityChangedInterface, like for example `node` and `block_content`. In a block template, which is a template of the configured block, you find it in the content array:

```
if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
  $changed_time = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->getChangedTime();
}
```

If you want to load the block content entity outside of the block template, see [How to get a field value of custom block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216672/how-to-get-a-field-value-of-custom-block)

Answer (score 1):

`$block->updated` should do the trick.