# Get block_content from block

Tags: blocks

What is the correct way to check if a block has an associated block_content instance, and if so, get the block_content object? What I have does not feel particularly intuitive or efficient:

```
/** @var \Drupal\block\Entity\Block $block */
$block;
$block_plugin = $block->getPlugin();
if ($block_plugin->getBaseId() == 'block_content') {
  /** @var \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent $block_content */
  $block_content = $block->getPlugin()->build()['#block_content'];
}
```

It feels weird to build the render array for the `$block_plugin` just to get access to the block content, but there doesn't seem to be a more helpful method on `$block` or `$block_plugin`.

For context: I'm conditionally updating block configuration in a deploy hook based on the block_content bundle, so I'm not rendering anything. Given that, it feels like I shouldn't be using the render array.

Comment: The UUID of the block_content entity is the second part of the plugin ID `[base_id]:[derivative_id]`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216672/how-to-get-a-field-value-of-custom-block

Comment: @4uk4 thanks a ton! This worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@4uk4's comment on the original problem pointed me to a better answer:

```
$block_plugin = $block->getPlugin();

$uuid = $block_plugin->getDerivativeId() ? $block_plugin->getDerivativeId() : '';

$block_content = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('block_content', $uuid);

if ($block_content) {...}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!